# Send UTF-16 encoded data with PHP curl

Tags: php, post, unicode, curl, utf-16

I'm building a php client to a web service that requires posted data to be encoded as UTF-16. How do i configure curl to encode my data in UTF-16 and also to decode the answer in UTF-16?

Some sample code:

```
$s = curl_init($url);

curl_setopt($s,CURLOPT_POST,1); 
curl_setopt($s,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
curl_setopt($s,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data);
curl_setopt($s,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
curl_setopt($s,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array('Content-Type: text/plain'));

$result = curl_exec($s);
curl_close($s);
```

Adding an Accept-Encoding header does not seem to do the trick. Is it possible to encode my $data string in UTF-16 first and then pass a byte array to curl instead of a string?

Thank you for your answers!

Comment: $data is UTF-16 encoded JSON-data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to find out what's *your* data encoding. Then, it's your choice. Both [iconv()](http://es.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php) and [mb_convert_encoding()](http://php.net/mb_convert_encoding) work pretty well.

Additionaly, you should inform about the encoding in the HTTP header:

```
curl_setopt($s,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-16'));
```

Comment: My data is hard-coded in the php, so i guess my data encoding is the encoding of the php file?

Comment: Correct. Good editors normally display the encoding in the status bar, or in the "Save as" dialogue.

Comment: Can't really get it to work but the problem might lie elsewhere... Will get back to this thread when I've solved it.

Comment: As I suspected the problem was elsewhere (little- vs big-endian serverside)